# Milo-netty-event-loop threads still open when disconnect my OPC UA Client

Tags: milo

I have a software for DIN 4.0 used to connect my software with device of industrial machine device. In this software i used "Milo Eclipse v0.6.6" library for OPC UA connection. When i create my OPC UA client, some threads, including "milo-netty-event-loop", are open and when i disconnect my OPC UA client this thread remain open. How i can close this threads?

I've already tried close this thread witch method "Stack.releaseSharedResources ();" but this close all thread and not just those related to the client i'm disconnecting.
This leads to all devices I currently have connected to malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

The event loop threads are shared by all client instances. The thread pool will exist for the lifetime of the application, or until `Stack.releaseSharedResources` is called.

Don't worry about it.

Comment: Okay. But why when i disconnect and re-connect the device, are opened 2 istance of this thread? One when i get the EndPoints and one when i create a client instance

Comment: These threads are part of a shared thread pool used by Netty that will exist for the lifetime of your application, or until `Stack.releaseSharedResources` is called. The number of threads may grow to a max of `2 * cpuCount`. See Netty's `NioEventLoopGroup` for more information.

Comment: And you know something about thread called "http-nio-<srvPort>-exec-<nOfIstance>"?